# count of days per month vs continuous date

Tags: oracle, date, date-range, continuous, sysdate

I got a SQL query that gives the date (D1) when a product has been in store and the date (D2) where the product went out. I want to calculate how many days did the product stay in stores. D2-D1 is the easy calc.
My issue is now if the product went in on 11/28 and went out on 12/03.

I want to show that it stayed 3 days in November and 3 days in December.
How can I proceed this? Looking for the number of days only for the month.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to use the first day of month for D2: `trunc(D2,'mm')`

```
select case when D1 < trunc(D2,'mm') then trunc(D2,'mm') - D1  
       else 0 end as days_previous_months,
        case when D1 < trunc(D2,'mm') then D2 - trunc(D2,'mm') + 1 
        else D2 -D1 + 1 end as in_month
from table1
```

Comment: thanks Miguel for your reply.
It's working fine except when product comes in the 1st day of the month and takes out the 5th, it shows 6 days whereas it only stays in 5 days, right? how can i proceed if the product is in on the 1st day or continuously from previous month?

Answer (score 3):

Even the first thing you said is incorrect: if you want the day count to include both the first and the last date, as you seem to, then the formula is D2 - D1 + 1, not D2 - D1.

Other than that, here is one way to do this. I assume you have a column for product_id but also a separate column for entry_id, since it is possible (even if it doesn't happen often) that the same product (with the same id) may "enter" and "exit" more than once. If the same product enters and exits twice in the same month, for six days and then again later for four more days, I assume you want those shown as SEPARATE counts, for the two "entry events" (as opposed to a single entry event of duration ten days).

Something like this. Note that I created some sample data in a WITH clause - which is there for testing only, not part of the SQL query (solution I propose).

```
with
  inputs (entry_id, product_id, date_in, date_out) as (
    select 1331, 101, date '2018-11-28', date '2018-12-03' from dual union all
    select 1332, 102, date '2018-03-09', date '2018-03-13' from dual union all
    select 1333, 102, date '2017-12-31', date '2018-03-01' from dual
  )
select entry_id, product_id,
       to_char(start_date, 'MON yyyy') as month,
       least(end_date, date_out) - greatest(start_date, date_in) + 1 as day_count
from   (
         select entry_id, product_id, date_in, date_out,
                add_months(trunc(date_in, 'mm'), level - 1) as start_date,
                add_months(trunc(date_in, 'mm'), level) - 1 as end_date
         from   inputs
         connect by level <= 1 + months_between(trunc(date_out, 'mm'), 
                                                trunc(date_in, 'mm'))
                and prior entry_id = entry_id
                and prior sys_guid() is not null
       )
order by product_id, start_date
;

  ENTRY_ID PRODUCT_ID MONTH              DAY_COUNT
---------- ---------- ----------------- ----------
      1331        101 NOV 2018                   3
      1331        101 DEC 2018                   3
      1333        102 DEC 2017                   1
      1333        102 JAN 2018                  31
      1333        102 FEB 2018                  28
      1333        102 MAR 2018                   1
      1332        102 MAR 2018                   5
```